# BindableCollection showing string but getting int from ComboBox

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

i have a `BindableCollectio<string>` with projects:

```
public BindableCollection<string> ProjectsList { get; set; }
public string SelectedProjectsList { get; set; } //project selected form combobox
```

For now i have only projects names in it. I binded that list to simple `ComboBox` in `WPF`.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectsList" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedProjectsList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

`Project` Model looks like this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

In `PorjectsList` i only storing names of `Project`.

My question is, can we retrive from `BindableCollection` project's `id` and still showing project name on combobox list? Or maybe there is better solution for it in `CaliburnMicro`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [SelectedValuePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=netframework-4.8) and [DisplayMemberPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?view=netframework-4.8) for the purpose.
You should begin by changing `ProjectsList` Property to type of `BindableCollection<Project>.`

```
public BindableCollection<Project> ProjectsList { get; set; }
public int SelectedProjectsList { get; set; }
```

Now, your Xaml

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectsList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedValue ="{Binding SelectedProjectsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

This would enable to display `Name` in Combobox, while getting `Id` when selecting the item.